# How to fully fit an image inside carousel(Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have made a fully functional carousel but the problem is that on the right side of carousel white block is appearing. I want to ged rid of that. Please help.

[image: Example]

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="Jellyfish.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2>This is the heading</h2>
      <p>This is paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="Koala.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2 style="color:orange">This is the heading</h2>
      <p>This is paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="Penguins.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2>This is the heading</h2>
      <p>This is paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <a href="#caro" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#caro" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this :-  .item img{width:100%}

Comment: Use images that are the right size for the carousel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set Image `width:100%`

```
.item img {
  width:100%
}
```

Here is Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u9kkdLzb/

Comment: Can u explain me this line
.item img {
  width:100%
}

Comment: Item div which content slider text and image of each slide in carousel. so that image coming in Item div.. for that css come like that..

Answer (score 4):

in your css set image width:100%

```css
.carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        margin:auto;
        width: 100%; // Add this
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="Jellyfish.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2>This is the heading</h2>
      <p>This is paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="Koala.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2 style="color:orange">This is the heading</h2>
      <p>This is paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="Penguins.jpg" alt="image">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h2>This is the heading</h2>
      <p>This is paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <a href="#caro" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#caro" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: i am a beginner in Bootstrap, can u edit the code and then post the full edited code that is working

Comment: .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img

Comment: can u explain me this line

Comment: can u explain me this line
.carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img

Comment: .carousel-inner is a class and .item also separate class... the image is within .item class and .carousel-inner class, so we apply image width like that.. it's like inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Theres also an easy way to implement this right in the carousel html structure. Every time you insert an img as an item, while still being inside the  tag, add style="width: 100%". so it would look something like this.

```html
<div class="item active">
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width: 100%">
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width: 100%">
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width: 100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work for modern browsers.
Works with bootstrap 5.
Height can be set to any value

```
#myCarousel .carousel-item img {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

source is:
https://raybo.org/posts/2021-03-27-consistent-height-carousels-with-css-gradients-by-hacking-the-bootstrap-5-carousel/

Comment: I dropped the height: 100vh, so that the image would scale proportionally for different screen sizes. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="~/images/IMAGE.jpg" alt="Important IMAGE" class="container-fluid" />
```

Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport. Please note images still need to be sized well before adding to your site, its [good practice](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/).

Comment: please add some description and explanation to answer

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem with a project. There are ways to fiddle with the image size via css but you will most likely end up with undesirable results such as squished or stretched looking images.

1 method is to use a div with a specified size, use css to set the image as a background image for the div and set background-size to fit, contain or cover.

2 A better approach is to use an image manipulation program like photoshop, i personally use an online application called https://www.photopea.com. Is is basically a free online version of photoshop. Just edit the image size and DPI and it will help retain a more correct aspect-ratio.